# How to convert value from double to Integer in jsp

Tags: jsp

Supposing that In the jsp file, I want to show the value which is computed as below :

```
<c:when test="${userProduct.term.label == 'tháng'}">
                                <c:if test="${userProduct.term.value %12==0}"> ${userProduct.term.value/12} năm</c:if>
```

Supposing that value = 36 and the number which I want to show to user is 3. However, the number which I received is 3.0.
Currently, I am looking for a way to show as I expected.
Please tell me know the way to do it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the *fmt:parseNumber* tag

```
<c:set var="yourValue" value="${userProduct.term.value/12}" />
<fmt:parseNumber var="intValue" integerOnly="true" 
                       type="number" value="${yourValue}" />
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_parsenumber_tag.htm

Answer (score -1):

You could use JSTL to accomplish this, specifically the [`<fmt:formatNumber>`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_formatnumber_tag.htm) tag.

```
<c:if test="${userProduct.term.value %12==0}">
    <fmt:formatNumber value="${userProduct.term.value/12}"
                      maxFractionDigits="0" />
    năm
</c:if>
```